# Object data type to numeric and categorical in python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a csv with columns of different datatypes. But when I read it into pandas, it shows everything as the object data type.

How do I convert the columns into the original numeric and categorical features?

Comment: Please, post the code.

Comment: `pandas` uses `object` dtype where it can't readily, or clearly, use a numeric dtype.  For example, a string in a column will force the whole Series to be object dtype.  Make sure you are handling column headers correctly.  Beyond that you many need to show us a sample of the `csv` and resulting dataframe.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand your point and that was kind of the error I got. I have given a rough sample code and data of how it looks like and how I have tried to solve it in the comments. Please let me know if there is any other efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do couple of things: For now here are some examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "a"], "B": ['1','4', '5', '8']})
df["C"] = df["A"].astype('category')
df["D"] = df["B"].astype('int')
```

output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   a   1   a   1
1   b   4   b   4
2   c   5   c   5
3   a   8   a   8

df.dtypes

A      object
B      object
C    category
D       int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

data=data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

This converted the numeric features into float and let the categorical variables remain as objects which I later label encoded to be fed into the model.

I am under a restriction of not to share the code or data but I have made a sample of it for reference.

[img of a sample code notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SoI7.png)

Note the first row of the data which has the data type of the column. I had removed the first row in later use.